# correct syntax for purrr::pmap when using a df as the .l input argument

Tags: r, purrr

I need some quick help with the correct syntax for `pmap`.

I have a modelling function into which I'm trying to feed a number of parameters. As the inputs are more than two, I need to use `pmap` and I simply can't work out the proper syntax.

Could someone please help me!

```
# My function
test_func <- function(lead_count,
                          mtry,
                          learn_rate,
                          tree_depth) { 
        paste(lead_count,
              mtry,
              learn_rate,
              tree_depth)
    }


# Input parameters for the function
model_parameter <-data.frame(lead_count = c(1),
                             mtry = c(24),
                             learn_rate = c(0.55),
                             tree_depth = c(9))


# This works    
test_func(lead_count = model_parameter$lead_count, mtry = model_parameter$mtry, 
          learn_rate = model_parameter$learn_rate, tree_depth = model_parameter$tree_depth)





## What I have tried unsuccessfully with pmap
pmap(model_parameter, test_func(lead_count     = lead_count,
                                    mtry       = mtry,
                                    learn_rate = learn_rate,
                                    tree_depth = tree_depth))


pmap(model_parameter, test_func(lead_count = ..1,
                                mtry       = ..2,
                                learn_rate = ..3,
                                tree_depth = ..4))
```

Comment: @akrun, I have, I want to replicate the same result produced by the function under `#This works` but using `pmap`, does that make sense?

Comment: Can you check the solution posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the column names of the 'model_parameter' matches the argument names off the function, we can do

```
pmap(model_parameter, test_func)
#[[1]]
#[1] "1 24 0.55 9"
```

---

If we need to specify the arguments, then use the anonymous function call `~`

```
pmap(model_parameter, ~ test_func(lead_count = ..1,
                            mtry       = ..2,
                            learn_rate = ..3,
                            tree_depth = ..4))
#[[1]]
#[1] "1 24 0.55 9"
```

Comment: @cephalopod  It is a little enigmatic  when you do it the first time.  Only thing to remember is `function(x)` is similar to `~` in tidyverse